# complex MDX query(s)

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a cube with the following structure

1 measure
sales count

three dimensions. 
brand, region, gender

i need an mdx query(s) that returns the following 8 tuples.

1. Total sales across all dimension attributes including unknown values
2. The single highest value of any combination of  attribute values for each dimension.
3. Total sales for the brand attribute identified by stat 2
4. Total sales for the region attribute identified by stat 2
5. Total sales for the gender attribute identified by stat 2
6. Total sales for the brand attribute by region attribute identified by stat 2 with all gender attributes
7. Total sales for the region attribute by gender attribute identified by stat 2 with all brand attributes
8. Total sales for the brand attribute by gender attribute identified by stat 2 with all region attributes

Comment: Have you tried writing the MDX queries? What did they return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query could perhaps be written using a CROSSJOIN to show all the possible combinations of brand, region and gender:

```
SELECT {
   {[Brand].defaultMember.children}*
   {[Region].defaultMember.children}*
   {[Gender].defaultMember.children}
} ON ROWS,
{[Measures].[Sales Count]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [your_cube_name]
```

Does that get you started?